# Arduino Nano - Why are my pins behaving the way they are?

Tags: c++, arduino, physics

I have a device that measures radiation, using an Elegoo Uno (knockoff Arduino brand) and an RM-60 Radiation Monitor from Aware Electronics. I have had this working for almost a year and a half as part of a high-altitude balloon payload item at my university. I am currently revisiting it, as now I want to understand and cleanup my code.

The setup goes like this:
The RM-60 has four wires. Yellow and black go to ground, red to my 5v, and the green goes to my output (More documentation can be found online).

I have a pin attached to digital 2. I had read online that pins 2 & 3 can use attachInterrputs for the Uno. But for whatever reason, setting my pinMode() to 2 won't work. I have found that when I set my pin to 8, with my actual wire connecting to digital 2, I can read it fine.

This is what I am confused about. I felt that after learning how these inputs work, I am doing it right. But it's not working. So then why, when my pin set to 8, is the device running correctly? If I am doing this wrong (or inefficiently), what tips or pointers can you give me on how to optimize/repair this?

I have my previous code, compiled and tested from almost two years ago. It works as is, but I just don't understand why. I have looked online for similar projects, as several balloon teams around the world have used RM-60s to measure radiation. Following their pin layout and program, I have been unsuccessful.

```
//this is taking just the necessary lines to run the geigercounter.
//using geigerPin 8, it works. But why not when I change this to 2, where my 
//wire actually is?

int count;
int geigerPin = 8; 
int testVar = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(geigerPin, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, test, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(count * 6);
  count = 0;
  delay(10000);
}

void test() {
  count++;
}
```

The data reads back to the Serial monitor every 10 seconds. The returned result should be the counts over ten seconds, multiplied by 6 to give us a counts-per-minute reading.

Comment: `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), test, RISING);` https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the manual befor using any functions. The manual clearly states that your approach is not going to work.

From the Arduino Reference Manual:

> `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), ISR, mode)` (recommended)
>
> `attachInterrupt(interrupt, ISR, mode)` (not recommended)
>
> `attachInterrupt(pin, ISR, mode)` (Not recommended. Additionally, this
>   syntax only works on Arduino SAMD Boards, Uno WiFi Rev2, Due, and
>   101.)
>
> Example Code
>
> ```
> const byte ledPin = 13;
> const byte interruptPin = 2;
> volatile byte state = LOW;
>
> void setup() {
>   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
>   pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
>   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), blink, CHANGE);
> }
>
> void loop() {
>   digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
> }
>
> void blink() {
>   state = !state;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried this approach before, but I must've forgotten a line or something.

But then for the second part of my question, why was my previous code and design working? Because I thought that unless the interrupt was attached to the correct pin, it just wouldn't work. But with my pin set to 8, this was reading just fine. Why is this?